# drupal Webform Issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I have created a tpl file for render the webform node.webform is working fine but after submit it returns to same page rather than goto thanks page. i want to redirect  the action to thanks page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually create your own page that you want your users to be directed to after submitting a webform, and provide whatever links you like on this page. To do this, edit the webform and go to Form Settings.  Under Submission Settings, click Customize Confirmation and choose "Redirect to a different page" from the jump menu.  Under path, provide the path to this page that you've created.